# Golang how to test function that return channel type?

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-testing, gomock

I try to test function StartP,
Expect that Start() should be called 1 times, Done() should be called 1 times

but I have trouble that test will block when run this step  **<-ps.Done()**

I expect <-ps.Done() return nil

How can I test function that return chan type?

```
// production code

func (s *vService) StartP(ctx context.Context, reason string) error {

    ps, err := s.factory.CreateVService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    ps.Start(reason)

    err = <-ps.Done()   // code stop here to wait ? how can i test ?

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

```
// test code

func Test_StartP(t *testing.T) {
    mockCtrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer mockCtrl.Finish()

    mockPService := mockpservice.NewMockPInterface(mockCtrl)

    vService := &vService {
                      factory: &servicefactory.FakeServiceFactory{
                                 MockPService: mockPService
                               }
                    }

    mockPService.EXPECT().Start("reason").Times(1).Return()
    mockPService.EXPECT().Done().Times(1).DoAndReturn(func() chan error {
        return nil
    })

    err := vService.StartP(context.Background(), "reason")
    assert.Equal(t, nil, err)
}
```

I use gomock to mock the  PServiceInterface

```
// interface

type PServiceInterface interface {
    Start(reason string)
    Done() <-chan error
}
```

gomock gen this function

```
func (m *MockProvisionServiceInterface) Done() <-chan error {
        m.ctrl.T.Helper()
        ret := m.ctrl.Call(m, "Done")
        ret0, _ := ret[0].(<-chan error)
        fmt.Println(ret0,".....mock Done()")
        return ret0
}
```

// I also try this

```
    mockProvisionService.EXPECT().Done().Times(1).DoAndReturn( func() chan error {
        fmt.Println("DoAndReturn...err nil")

        ch := make(chan error, 1)
        ch <- nil
        return ch
    })
```

Comment: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Receive_operator: *"Receiving from a nil channel __blocks forever__. A receive operation on a closed channel can always __proceed immediately__, ..."* -- So what you can probably do is, in your mock implementation, or in `DoAndReturn`, instead of returning `nil` as the channel from `Done()`, return a properly initialized but closed channel; then `err = <-ps.Done()` should not block anymore and instead return immediately.

Comment: @mkopriva i also modify other method ,
I write the last part of the article, but still not work.
Hope you write down code, let me get your idea correctly.

Comment: What I meant by "returning a closed channel" is something like this: `ch := make(chan error)`; `close(ch)`; `return ch`. If that doesn't unblock the `err = <-ps.Done()` then I'm not sure what will, I'm not familiar enough with gomock to know exactly how to make it work.

Comment: i also add close(ch);  then return ch ,  still not work

Comment: I have found root cause. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, root cause is DoAndReturn something wrong.

Func type should be **<-chan error**, not **chan error**

```
 mockProvisionService.EXPECT().Done().Times(1).DoAndReturn( func() <-chan error{
            fmt.Println("DoAndReturn...err nil")
            ch := make(chan error, 1)
            ch <- nil
            return ch
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

The following shows, I think, the minimum code to implement your test goals.

It does not use any mocking framework because in my experience they tend to obfuscate the test intent, require everybody in the team to learn how to use them and are not needed, at least in Go. One could also wonder what the test is actually testing...

First, let's add some missing production code:

```golang
type factoryInterface interface {
    CreateVService(ctx context.Context) (PServiceInterface, error)
}

type vService struct {
    factory factoryInterface
}
```

And now the test code, in three parts: the factory, the mock, and the test.

The test factory:

```golang
type testFactory struct {
    mock PServiceInterface
}

func (f *testFactory) CreateVService(ctx context.Context) (PServiceInterface, error) {
    return f.mock, nil
}
```

The mock:

```golang
type ServiceMock struct {
    records []string
}

func (sm *ServiceMock) Start(reason string) {
    sm.records = append(sm.records, "start")
}

func (sm *ServiceMock) Done() <-chan error {
    sm.records = append(sm.records, "done")
    ch := make(chan error)
    close(ch)
    return ch
}
```

And finally the test:

```golang
func TestWithMock(t *testing.T) {
    mock := ServiceMock{}
    sut := &vService{factory: &testFactory{&mock}}

    err := sut.StartP(context.Background(), "banana")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("StartP: have: %s; want: no error", err)
    }

    if have, want := len(mock.records), 2; have != want {
        t.Fatalf("number of mock calls: have: %v; want: %v", have, want)
    }

    if have, want := mock.records[0], "start"; have != want {
        t.Fatalf("mock call 1: have: %v; want: %v", have, want)
    }

    if have, want := mock.records[1], "done"; have != want {
        t.Fatalf("mock call 2: have: %v; want: %v", have, want)
    }
}
```

The three assertions on the mock call sequence can be collapsed into one, comparing directly the slice `[]string{"start", "done"}`, if one is using a test library such as the excellent `assert` package of https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotest.tools

Comment: Your concept is perfect. I have found root cause. Thank you!

Comment: @Y.Ryan If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it. This helps future users and gives me an incentive to keep answering questions.